# Excel 2010/2013 SUMIFS formula with Table references, Named cells, and Year ranges?

Tags: excel, formulas, named, sumifs

I have a Table in Excel that contains yearly usage data for some products.  For example, I have Product A with usage stats from 2003 to 2014.  The table is referenced via several Named ranges to be used in formulas.  **Usage_Product** is the column name of the products, **Usage_Year** is the Year, and **Usage_Grand_Total** is the total for all months in that year.

I have a basic data chart built using formulas that key off of a Named cell reference called **YearSelected**.  The cell contains a list of years, allowing the user to select the Year they want to see usage for.  The following formula works fine when the year is selected:

```
=SUMIFS(Usage_Grand_Total,Usage_Product,A3,Usage_Year,YearSelected)
```

*A3 is a reference to a cell that contains the specific product name that matches the Table data.*

However, I would like to get a sum that includes all prior years instead of just the one selected.  I tried the following formula (and variations of it) without success:

```
=SUMIFS(Usage_Grand_Total,Usage_Product,A3,Usage_Year,"<"&YearSelected)
```

This returns 0 for some reason.  Even if I do "<"&2014 or "<2014", I get the same 0.  I do a lot of similar types of formulas, but this one has me stumped.  The basic goal is to have a running summary of usage for the start of each selected year.  Any ideas on using the right formula option?

Comment: BTW, if I use an array like {"2003","2004","2005"} to match Usage_Year, the Sums total correctly for those years.  However, I need something dynamic and don't want to hardcode formulas like this.  If there's another way to create this dynamic array, that may work, too.

Comment: Sounds like your entries in the Usage_Year column are not numerical, but text. Test them with the ISNUMBER function.

Comment: To create your dynamic array you could use this setup: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Usage_Grand_Total,Usage_Product,A3,Usage_Year,ROW(INDIRECT("2003:"&YearSelected))))` assuming 2003 is the first possible year. But possibly better to convert the Usage_Year column to numbers as XOR LX implies

Comment: Yeah, turned out to be the data type.  Even though I had changed the fields to Number, they were still being evaluated as Text.  I created a new column to the Table called Usage_YearNum and made the value =VALUE(Year).  This converted the text field to a number value.  Then I changed the main SUMIFS formula to use the new Name and it worked.  Thanks XOR LX for pointing me in the ISNUMBER direction.